# XML schema method naming inconsistency

Tags: java, xsd

I am hoping someone has experienced this issue and can maybe shed some light.

I have an xml schema and an ant build file. The output .java files differ when I run ant on Windows versus Mac, even if I am using the same jaxb-xjc.jar to do the xml-compiling. The Windows side is naming the "getter" methods for attributes as "getX". The Mac side wants to name them "isX". Anyone experience anything like this before and/or have a solution? This is consistent between Windows Vista & 7 doing this the one way and Mac OSX 10.6 & 10.7 (untested on Mac OSX 10.8) doing it the other.

----edit----

I'll attach some of the code from the ant build.xml file.

Telling it what the xjc is.

```
<taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

Here is the 'actual' compiling:

Compiling the automaton schema

```
    <echo>Compiling old automaton schema</echo>
    <xjc schema="${oldxml-schema}" destdir="${src.dir}" package="${oldxml.package}">
        <produces dir="${oldxml-gen.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </xjc>

    <echo>Compiling the plugin schema</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${plugin-gen.dir}" />
     <xjc schema="${plugin-schema}" destdir="${src.dir}" package="${plugin.package}">
         <produces dir="${plugin-gen.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </xjc>

    <echo>Compiling the pluginDesumaSide schema</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${pluginDesumaSide-gen.dir}" />
     <xjc schema="${pluginDesumaSide-schema}" destdir="${src.dir}" package="${pluginDesumaSide.package}">
        <produces dir="${pluginDesumaSide-gen.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </xjc>
</target>
```

All targets (by that I mean anything mentioned like ${}) are defined and every links and compiles right except for Mac naming the 'getter' methods as 'is' methods for variables. They are boolean attributes that do have defaults if non-specified.

Comment: Please include more information. What tool are you using with this XML Schema? It appears you are generating code?

Comment: What versions of the JDK are you using?

Comment: @JohnSaunders
BlaiseDoughan

The inconsistency has been spotted with Java 1.6.23, 1.6.26 for Mac & Windows and the Windows running 1.7.? generates getX functions.

I am using the jaxb-xjc.jar binding compiler. When I run java -jar jaxb-xjc.jar -version it responds "hudson-jaxb-ri-2.1-661". I am using the schema to generate classes which are later used to 'load' xml files for the program.

Comment: does it generate `isX` for all methods or just specific ones?

Comment: @ftom2

On Mac, it generates isX methods for all boolean attributes. On Windows I am getting only getX.

Comment: That is weird, basically it is supposed to generate isX for boolean values, so the mac behaviour is correct. you run the exact same command with the exact same xsd's?

Comment: @ftom2 Yes. The same build file, the same java versions, the same build jar, the same targets, the same everything and the windows is consistently generating getX's. I do really appreciate being told the Mac is correct (gives me a starting point); the documentation can get daunting to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the responses I got I was able to google for a solution. Apparently this naming inconsistency and another (a getter returning a primitive but the setter only accepting objects) was apparent by chance for older xml-compilers due to some inconsistency in the specification.

This was fixed by going to http://jaxb.java.net/ and getting a new jaxb-impl.jar & jaxb-xjc.jar. I downloaded and ran the jaxb.jar file download and it created the needed jars.